# AngularJS - How to do a global object instead communicating into different controllers its modifications?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why the globalObj get the modification, and why this modification has effect into the secondo controller?

```
var globalObj = [{..},{..},{..}];

mymod = angular.module("app", []);

//CONTROLLER "first"
mymod.controller("first", function($scope){
   $scope.myobj = globalObj;
   //do something with $scope.myobj, as add, remove or modify some element
});

//FACTORY
mymod.factory("myfact", function(){
   objfact = function(someparam){
      this.obj = globalObj;
      //do something with this.obj
   }
   return objfact;   
});

//CONTROLLER "second"
mymod.controller("second", function($scope, myfact){
   $scope.otherMyObj = globalObj;
   myfact.objfact($scope.otherMyObj);
});
```

Comment: You are assigning the reference of globalObj. Anyone can change it and anyone having the reference would get affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're assigning both local controller variables (`myObj` and `myOtherObj`) to the same global variable. Please note that the following is a reference copy, it will **not** create a new variable with the same properties:

```
var myObj = someGlobalObj;
```

You could either use [angular.copy](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) or a far better approach would be to introduce a service that returns you the object, rather than exposing it on the global (JavaScript) scope.

Answer (score 0):

use a service

```
    sampleApp.service('sharedProperties', function () {

      var property = 'First';

        return {
            getProperty: function () {
                return property;
            },
            setProperty: function(value) {
                property = value;

            }
        }
});
```

in controller call
sharedProperties.getProperty() to get the value

sharedProperties.setProperty(value) to set the value